# Why this request doesn't work?

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to make a simple stupid twitter app using Twitter API.

If I request this page from my browser it does work:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=hello&rpp=10&page=1
```

but if I request this page from python using urllib or urllib2 most of the times it doesn't work:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=hello&rpp=10&page=1")
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter.py", line 24, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=hello&rpp=10&page=1")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1161, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1136, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Why ??

Comment: Are you sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: no I am sitting behind a router at my home :)

Comment: Do you have curl installed. Can you try out : curl -v 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=hello&rpp=10&page=1'. If this times out then there is some configuration on your browser that requires investigation.

Answer (score 2):

The code seems alright.

The following worked.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import urllib2
>>> user_agent = 'curl/7.21.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.4.0) libcurl/7.21.1'
>>> url='http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=hello&rpp=10&page=1'
>>> headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
>>> req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> the_page = response.read()
>>> print the_page
```

The other is twitter actually could not respond. This happens once too often with Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

did you change the default socket timeout somewhere in your script? your example code works reliably for me.

it could be your internet connection, or you might try

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
```

assuming urllib/2 don't override the socket timeout.

Comment: no I haven't change anything. Some times it work for me as well but most of times NOT. Try more times please :D

Comment: If it works sometimes and not others, then the problem is likely what the error says - your connection is timing out.

Comment: I ran it a hundred times in a loop and none of them timed out.

Comment: you can try increasing the socket timeout as described, maybe change the number from 30 to something higher. again, I don't know how urllib2 handles timeouts.

Comment: mmm very strange :(. I have increased the socket timeout as you described ( 30 50 and 100 ) but it still doesn't work :(