# Sending queries to google using python

Tags: python, api, search

I need a code with which I can send queries to Google and get the results back for some processing. i am mostly interested in retrieving the snippets of the results. It would be nice if I can do this without installing any extra packages for Python. A pre-written api would also do the trick.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple url based fetching technique using urllib2:

- [Why this request doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964519/why-this-request-doesnt-work/3964547#3964547)

See an example with google API

- http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets
- http://dcortesi.com/2008/05/28/google-ajax-search-api-example-python-code/

Comment: thanks. but as i mentioned, I need the snippets generated by google for each returned link and not the whole webpage.

Comment: @Hossein: The page is a result page which should contain the snippets. You could parse and get it. Of course the easier way would be to use Google Apis